# How to find time complexity of Breadth First Search for this tree?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, search, breadth-first-search

[image]

This is what I got from another forum, but honestly doesn't make much sense to me.

> Time complexity for a single tree doesn't make a lot of sense, since the function in the big O notation might be nowhere near the actual computation time. Time complexity is all about how the algorithm scales as the inputs get larger. You can calculate the exact number of traversals needed, though.

Answer (score 2):

It's true, time complexity for a single tree doesn't make sense. Aysmptotic notations are used to get bounds of how the algorithm scales in terms of its input size. The usual time complexity for BFS is given as $O(V^2)$ if adjacency matrix is used and $O(V+E)$ if adjacency list is used. This is however for a fixed no. of nodes.

Here a slightly modified analysis, which is used widely in the context of AI is better suited. Let $b$ be the branching factor, i.e. the maximum no. of children for any node in the tree and $d$ be the depth of the tree. Then an asymptotic upper bound for BFS would be $O(b^d)$.

Comment: Then how did we derived $O(b^d)$ ?

Comment: a node can have at most b children, so at level 1 you have b nodes, at level 2 each of the previous level nodes can have at max b children so b*b = b^2, at level 3 b^3 .. similarly at level d you have b^d. Sum up all the levels to get the answer